# Where do you store uploaded user images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, carrierwave

I am not yet using a service such as Amazon S3, so where in the file structure should I store uploaded user images? I want to avoid the public directory as the images are private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a plugin to handle your uploads? Many of them allow you to specify a path to store files, if you want to avoid the public folder a reasonable suggestion would be `"#{RAILS_ROOT}/uploads/images/"`

It's very much a matter of personal taste though.

For example in a carrierwave uploader this will place items in an uploads folder below RAILS_ROOT which is not publicly accessible.

```
def store_dir
  "#{RAILS_ROOT}/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end
```

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#changing-the-storage-directory

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was thinking about the "lib" or "vendor" folders?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend either of those folders, they have fairly well defined usage already. It's perfectly fine to create your own folder structure for these uploads.